# Sending Data to database without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

i'm trying to send data to my database without refreshing the page.

This is my code:

```
  // Submit code to the database 

  $(document).on("click", "#pin", function(){
  $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), $("#myForm").serialize(), function(info){                  
  $("#result").html(info);});
  });


  // Prevent the form to refresh the page.

  $('form#myForm').submit(function(event){    
  event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Now when I try to upload something to my database and do not use the second part of the code, everyting works well(The correct ID is submitted to my database, example: ID 47 is submitted into database).

But when i use the second part of my code(prevent the page from refreshing) it always send an ID of 5 to the database (that is the first ID in my product-table).

So everything works very well exept when i prevent the page from refreshing the wrong ID(eg: the first ID) is sent to the database and i have no clue why..

EDIT:

This is the HTML form. it is a php generated

```
  <?php 
  include 'connection.php';

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produitsinfo");
  $categorie = 'Pour-Lui';


    //Get all the data from database

  if ($result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produitsinfo WHERE categorie = '$categorie' OR                     
     categorie2 = '$categorie' OR categorie3 = '$categorie' OR categorie4 = '$categorie' OR 
            categorie5 = '      $categorie'")){

      // This is how each individual item get outputted to my page.

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){


      // Get product-data from database(dont mind this)

      echo '<div class="panel panel-default" id="item">
               <div class="panel-body" id="bodyitem">
<div><a href="' . $row['amazonlink'] . '"><img src="pictures/' . $row['picture'] . '" alt="' .   
          $row['description'] .'"></a></div>
                <div class="caption">
                  <h3 class="prix">Prix: ' . $row['prix'] . ' €</h3>
                  <p class="stars"><b>' . $row['rating'] .' Stars</b></p>
                      <a href="' . $row['amazonlink'] . '">
                       <div><p id="description">' .row['description'] .'<p></div></a>




          // Form to send data to database

             <form id="myForm" action="insert/insertip.php" method="post">
                <div id="span"><?php echo $row["description"] ?></div>
                <input type="text" id="ideee" name="idee" value="' . $lol . '">
                <input type="submit" value="Pin It" id="pin">
             </form>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
            }
 }
  else
 {
      echo (mysqli_error($con));
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: Do you have more than one form with the id of `myForm`?

Comment: Hi.Please post you html of the form

Comment: Hello, the forms are all with an ID myForm as you can see in my updated question. should i change it to a class?

Comment: Its illegal to have same id for multiple DOM nodes, change it to class.

Comment: I changed it to class and it works perfectly! after more than 24h of headbanging pfew! Thanks all, Sean do you have a better solution to do this? i thought this was ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js code will be like

```
$('form.myForm').submit(function(event){    
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post( $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(info){                  
    $("#result").html(info);
  });
});
```

Note:
You have to change the form id to class.

Comment: It stopped working for a moment again and then i used this code and worked just fine! thank you so much :)

Comment: @user3650471 glad this helped, marking this as an answer is greatly appreciated :)